# SAS PROC EXPORT "The server is disconnected."

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sas, export-to-excel

I am executing a stored procedure on a SQL server and exporting the results to excel. I do this with plenty of different stored procedures, so I just use the same sas code and change the stored procedure line to the proper procedure.

Today, I am catching an error as soon as my program executes PROC EXPORT. The error is:

```
An error occurred executing the workspace job "Program".
The server is disconnected.
```

The PROC EXPORT code:

```
PROC EXPORT
    DATA = output_final
    DBMS=xlsx 
    OUTFILE="&EXPORTPATH&FILE"
    REPLACE;
RUN;
```

Here is the weird thing, it still exports the file to that location, but the error stops the program there. I use this same exact code snippet in plenty of other programs. No one on my team knows what to make of this. I've tried it with DBMS=xls, DBMS=EXECELC, and DBMS=XLSX - no matter what, there is some sort of error related to the server or not access to the folder.

Before someone says "check your &EXPORTPATH," I have, it's fine, all the other sas programs I execute use that variable.

You may also be thinking, "if it exports the file, what's the problem?" Well, I need the program to move past this and do other things, so it can't have any errors. Plus..that's just sloppy!

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: This is a good candidate for SAS Tech Support.  http://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform//createForm

Comment: I would wrap a proc printto around the proc export to catch the error that is produced in SAS. I assume the error you put here is just what is displayed in EG?

Comment: @StigEide Yes, that error is a pop up window with an OK button. Shouldn't the error still be displayed in the log anyway? (it isn't) This makes me wonder if proc printto would even catch it. I haven't used proc printto before, but as I am reading, it must print out to a printer? If that is the case, it's not really what I am looking for :(

Comment: No, proc printto is used to redirect the log or output to files. Add this: before the code: filename log "/path/to/log.txt";proc printto log=log;run; And add this to the end to stop the redirect: proc printto;run;